# How to concatenate all rows in SQL Server 2008 using inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here are the 2 tables:

**users**

```
row_id  user_id
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
```

**usernames**

```
user_id    username
1          foo
2          bar
3          test
```

How can I group by row_id, join both tables and concatenate the usernames?  For example:

**Query should return**

```
row_id     username
1          foo, bar, test
2          foo
```

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you need to use the XML hack:

```
select r.row_id,
       stuff( (select ', ' + un.username
               from users u join
                    usernames un
                    on u.user_id = un.user_id
               where u.row_id = r.row_id
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as names
from (select distinct row_id from users) r;
```

More recent versions of SQL Server support `string_agg()` making this method superfluous.